# sidebar navigation and top navbar conflict

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

If you go to the below page for bootstrap 3.0.3, and use the sidebar navigation to go to Migrating from 2.x to 3.0 (which has subfields once you click it), you may notice that the h3 header text "Migrating from 2.x to 3.0" appears nicely below the top navbar. But if you click the subnav links under "Migrating from 2.x to 3.0" on the sidenavbar, such as the first one, "Major Class Changes", it jumps to this section, but the title is covered up by the top navbar!

Go here:
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

I can't figure out how it is doing this correctly for the parent navigation links, but not the children. I want to make it work right for the child links too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing the same thing for both anchors, but the larger headers have a lot more `margin-top` that likely unintentionally make it look good. Anchors will scroll the window to put the anchor even with the top of the viewport. With a `position: fixed` navbar, the navbar will sit on top of any anchors that have less `margin-top` than the height of the nav.

Here's the `h1#migration` anchor with its glorious 45px top margin:

[image: 45px margin-top]

And here's the `h2#migration-classes` with its 0px of top margin:

[image]

Both were scrolled to the top of the viewport on clicking the anchor, but the `h2` was positioned underneath the `position: fixed` navigation.